# Can't install amazon-linux-extras pm AWS EC2 Amazon Linux AMI instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-linux

I'm trying to install amazon-linux-extras using the [instructions here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-install-extras-library-software/):

```
sudo yum install -y amazon-linux-extras
```

And I get the following error:

```
amzn-main                                                                                                                             | 2.1 kB  00:00:00     
amzn-updates                                                                                                                          | 3.8 kB  00:00:00     
839 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
No package amazon-linux-extras available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Why is the package not available?

I have EPEL installed, so I don't understand what's going on.

**UPDATE**

Output of

`sudo yum repolist`

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
843 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
repo id                       repo name                                               status
!amzn-main/latest             amzn-main-Base                                               5,934
!amzn-updates/latest          amzn-updates-Base                                            4,722
epel/x86_64                   Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64          12,517+843
repolist: 23,173
```

Comment: can you please show the output of the following command `sudo yum repolist`

Comment: @BANJOSA I updated the question with the output of the command you asked. what do you think i should do?

Comment: did you solve this? same problem here.

Comment: Do you have to set yum repo list explicitly? my ec2 server has no yum repos and im struggling to find and add them.

Comment: Amazon Linux 2022, the successor for 2, has removed `amazon-linux-extras` 
[see documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2022/release-notes/removed-packages-al2022.html)

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same error message when attempting to create an Amazon Linux 2 instance using the AWS CDK. The CDK currently defaults to Amazon Linux instead of Amazon Linux 2. When you accidentally use an Amazon Linux AMI from 2018, surprise surprise, all sorts of facilities are not available.
I posted an [easy way to check your version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66128557/203860) in another answer.

In CDK (and Cloud Formation) make sure to declare your intended *generation* in your AmazonLinuxImage properties

```
generation: AmazonLinuxGeneration.AMAZON_LINUX_2
```

Comment: I wish i could upvote this more.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks.  Should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this issue is potentially being caused by YUM priorities.  You could try disabling priorities to see if that is the issue.  The config file used to disable yum priorities can be found here.

```
/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/priorities.conf
```

Change the config to be "enabled = 0" and try again.

Comment: still the same for me...

Comment: downvoted: generally does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can't install `amazon-linux-extras` on Amazon Linux 2018 AMI

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to install on EC2 instance of AMI "Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM)"